# liberty:devc: <dockerfile> not being honored

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I observe that the `<dockerfile>` element, though it points to a valid `Dockerfile` is not honored by `liberty:devc`.

Consider this output from `mvn help:effective-pom`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>javaee-cafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-cafe-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
  <groupId>javaee-cafe</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-cafe-jcache</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>javaee-cafe-jcache</name>
  <properties>
    <dockerFileName>Dockerfile</dockerFileName>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <!-- elided -->
    <usrDirectory>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr</usrDirectory>
  </properties>
  <dependencies><!-- elided --></dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <!-- elided -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <directory>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target</directory>
    <finalName>javaee-cafe-jcache</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <!-- elided -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>package-server</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>create</goal>
              <goal>install-feature</goal>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <container>true</container>
              <dockerfile>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/Dockerfile</dockerfile>
              <libertyRuntimeVersion>[21.0.0.5,)</libertyRuntimeVersion>
              <serverXmlFile>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml</serverXmlFile>
              <copyDependencies><!-- elided --></copyDependencies>
              <outputDirectory>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/wlp-package</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn liberty:devc` I see this output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< javaee-cafe:javaee-cafe-jcache >-------------------
[INFO] Building javaee-cafe-jcache 1.0.3
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- liberty-maven-plugin:3.3.4:devc (default-cli) @ javaee-cafe-jcache ---
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using artifact based assembly archive : io.openliberty:openliberty-kernel:null:21.0.0.5:zip.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using installDirectory : /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using serverName : defaultServer.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using serverDirectory : /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer.
<!-- elided -->
[INFO] Running liberty:deploy
[INFO] The liberty.runtime.version property value [21.0.0.5,) is used for the runtimeArtifact version.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using artifact based assembly archive : io.openliberty:openliberty-kernel:null:21.0.0.5:zip.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using installDirectory : /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using serverName : defaultServer.
[INFO] CWWKM2102I: Using serverDirectory : /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer.
[INFO] Copying 1 file to /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer
[WARNING] The /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/src/main/liberty/config/server.xml file is overwritten by the /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml file.
[INFO] Copying 1 file to /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer
[INFO] CWWKM2144I: Update server configuration file server.xml from /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml.
[INFO] CWWKM2144I: Update server configuration file bootstrap.properties from inlined configuration.
<!-- elided -->
[INFO] CWWKM2185I: The liberty-maven-plugin configuration parameter "appsDirectory" value defaults to "apps".
[INFO] CWWKM2160I: Installing application javaee-cafe-jcache.war.xml.
[INFO] Parsing the server file /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml for features and includes.
[INFO] Copying 1 file to /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer
[INFO] CWWKM2144I: Update server configuration file server.xml from /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/src/main/liberty/config/server.xml.
[INFO] CWWKM2144I: Update server configuration file bootstrap.properties from inlined configuration.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.665 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-10T18:05:42-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin:3.3.4:devc (default-cli) on project javaee-cafe-jcache: No Dockerfile was found at /home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/Dockerfile. Create a Dockerfile at the specified location to use dev mode with container support. For an example of how to configure a Dockerfile, see https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.docker -> [Help 1]
<!-- elided -->
Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Jun 10 18:05:42
```

It looks like the `<dockerfile>`, though it exists, is not being honored.

```xml
<dockerfile>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/Dockerfile</dockerfile>
```

Is this a bug?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLUTION:  Use plugin-level configuration (not execution-level)

You need to add your configuration at the plugin level rather than the execution level.

So it should look more like:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <dockerfile>/home/edburns/workareas/open-liberty-on-aks/javaee-app-redisson/target/Dockerfile</dockerfile>
          <!-- ... rest of config ... -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

The `liberty:dev` and `liberty:devc` goals kind of encapsulate a lifecycle inside a single goal, executed iteratively in a loop, but there isn't as much use for execution-level config.  (Not sure this is really documented that well.)

#### OTHER THOUGHTS

If you look at the [pom.xml](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/guide-docker/blob/prod/finish/pom.xml) in our sample guides like [this one](https://openliberty.io/guides/docker.html) you'll see we don't even bother configuring other Liberty goals like create, deploy, etc. bound to phases like package.

We just use liberty:dev and liberty:devc to do iterative development, then when it's time to build the image, we do `mvn package` to let the maven-war-plugin build the war, then do the Docker build to build the WAR into the app image.

Of course you may have a reason to include this, and I'm getting off topic, but just adding some more context here.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/1157 to follow-up and maybe doc better.